# FuelPHP Migrations for different tables

Tags: php, migration, fuelphp

I am just starting using FuelPHP and struggling with how migrations work.

I have created a migration called 001_products.php and this works great.

I then created a new migration for a currency table called 001_currencies.php but the oil refine migrate command ignores it and says everything is up to date.

If I rename the file to 002_currencies.php it creates the table, but I thought that each table had to have its own sequential numbering of the migration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuel's migrations require a unique number prefix to ensure that migrations are executed in the same order each time. It's 001, 002, 003, etc, globally, not per-table.